# A program to display, update and save a dictionary as .csv

Tags: python, beginner, console, csv, hash-map

*I'm now looking for feedback on [v2.0 of this program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59975/a-module-to-display-update-and-save-a-dictionary-as-csv-v2-0) instead.*

I'd like some feedback about my code. What bad habits do I have? What advice could help me write more Pythonic?

I'm trying to write a console application and want a tool to display, update and save settings in a dictionary.

```
def file_as_string(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as opened_file:
        string = opened_file.read().replace('\n', '')
        return string

def csv_as_dict(file_name):
    file_name = file_name + '.csv'
    import csv
    dictionary = {}
    for key, value in csv.reader(open(file_name)):
        dictionary[key] = value
    return dictionary

def print_formatted_dict(dictionary, key_title , value_title):
    print "{:^30} {:^15}".format('%s', '%s') % (key_title, value_title)
    for setting, value in dictionary.items():
        print "{:<30} {:<15}".format(setting, value)

def generic_prompt(prompt):
    value = raw_input(prompt)
    return value

def prompt_for_item(prompt, item):
    prompt = prompt + ' ' + item + ': '
    value = raw_input(prompt)        
    return value

def change_dict_value(dictionary, prompt, item):
    value = prompt_for_item(prompt, item)
    dictionary[item] = (value)
    return dictionary

def csv_save_dict(dictionary, file_name): 
    file_name = file_name + '.csv'
    import csv
    csv_file = csv.writer(open(file_name, "w"))
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        csv_file.writerow([key, value])    

def change_dict(dictionary):
    specify_question = 'Specify'
    change_question = 'Change settings? '
    setting_question = 'Setting to change: '
    save_question = 'Save settings? '

    change_answer = generic_prompt(change_question)
    while change_answer not in yes_no:
        change_answer = generic_prompt(change_question)
    while change_answer == 'yes':
        change_item = generic_prompt(setting_question)
        while change_item not in dictionary:
            change_item = generic_prompt(setting_question)
        dictionary = change_dict_value(dictionary, specify_question, change_item)
        print_formatted_dict(dictionary, key_title, value_title)
        change_answer = generic_prompt(change_question)
        while change_answer not in yes_no:
            change_answer = generic_prompt(change_question)
        if change_answer == 'no':
            save_answer = generic_prompt(save_question)
            while save_answer not in yes_no:
                save_answer = generic_prompt(save_question)
            if save_answer == 'yes':
                filename_answer = generic_prompt(filename_question)
                csv_save_dict(dictionary, filename_answer)
    return dictionary

def load_dict(dictionary):
    load_answer = generic_prompt(load_question)
    while load_answer not in yes_no:
        load_answer = generic_prompt(load_question)
    if load_answer == 'yes':
        filename_answer = generic_prompt(filename_question)
        dictionary = csv_as_dict(filename_answer)
        print_formatted_dict(dictionary, key_title, value_title)
    if load_answer == 'no':
        pass
    return (dictionary, load_answer)

def load_change_loop(dictionary, load_answer):
    while load_answer == 'yes':
        dictionary = change_dict(dictionary)
        dictionary, load_answer = load_dict(dictionary)
    return dictionary

def main():
    default_dict = csv_as_dict(default_settings)
    print_formatted_dict(default_dict, key_title, value_title)
    dictionary = load_change_loop(default_dict, load_answer)
    return dictionary

#string variables
default_settings = 'default_settings'
load_question = 'Load a dictionary? '
filename_question = 'File name: '
key_title = 'Setting'
value_title = 'Value'
load_answer = 'yes'

#list variables
yes_no = ['yes', 'no']

main()
```

The console with highlighted user input looks like this:
[image: Console]

The program begins by reading a default_settings.csv file, mine looks like this:
[image: Excel]

Comment: A CSV up file and your output are both just text; please provide them as such, rather than as screenshots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pretty good program for a beginner.

A few points:

Put your `import csv` once at the top of the file, not in the functions that use csv. Importing is best thought of as an action at the start of your program, not as something that happens while performing an action.

You do this a lot:

```
while load_answer not in yes_no:
    load_answer = generic_prompt(load_question)
if load_answer == 'yes':
```

Anytime you find yourself repeating code, it'd be helpful to write a function instead. Something like:

```
   def ask_boolean_question(prompt):
       answer = ''
       while answer not in yes_no:
           answer = generic_prompt(prompt)
       return answer == 'yes'
```

Now your code can simply say:

```
  if ask_boolean_question(load_question):
```

And avoid repeating the loop everytime you ask a question.

Your program doesn't make its structure very clear. Given what your program does, your main function should read something like:

```
def main():
    manipulate_settings(default_settings)
    while ask_boolean_question(load_question):
         filename = generic_prompt(filename_question)
         manipulate_settings(filename)
```

Note that by reading this, you can see the program processes first the default settings, and then as many other settings files as you have inclination to use the program.

Answer (score 2):

You have taken quite an odd approach to splitting this up into functions. For example, `generic_prompt` is totally pointless;

```
value = generic_prompt(prompt)
```

adds nothing over:

```
value = raw_input(prompt)
```

and just makes your code harder to read. And yet, as Winston points out, you have repeated the code for a yes/no input over and over again. `prompt_for_item` (`value = raw_input('%s %s: ' % (prompt, item))`) and `change_dict_value` (`dictionary[item] = raw_input(...)`) also seem suspect.

---

Both `change_dict` and `change_dict_value` mutate their argument *and* `return` it. This is unconventional; typically, functions that mutate arguments `return None`, implicitly or explicitly.

---

```
def csv_save_dict(dictionary, file_name): 
    file_name = file_name + '.csv'
    ...
```

It seems odd to expect the filename passed to a function to save a CSV to not include the extension. You should check this when the user *inputs* the filename, or at the very least guard this change with:

```
if not file_name.endswith('.csv'):
```

*(although note that it's not actually necessary to call the file a .csv; the user may have specified a different extension)*

Also, I would call this `save_dict_as_csv`, or just `export_dict` (now you don't have to rename if you switch from `csv` to e.g. `pickle`).

---

Some of your "constants" (usually `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` in Python) seem oddly-placed. For example, `key_title` and `value_title` could be moved inside `print_formatted_dict`, removing the need for two arguments that only pass constants along. You could also make an input function `get_filename`, called for both importing and exporting, where `filename_question` could be moved to (this would also allow you to later add checking that the file in question does/doesn't exist, or switch to a file chooser). In both cases, I would just have a literal string, rather than separately define it, e.g.:

```
print "{:^30} {:^15}".format('%s', '%s') % ("Setting", "Value")
```

---

Your code has no explanation whatsoever. At the very least, you should add in some docstrings (see [PEP-257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)) outlining what each function does.

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to follow code style guidelines from [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [Google](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)
if you want to write more Pythonic code.

To be more specific:

```
    dictionary = change_dict_value(dictionary, specify_question, change_item)
```

Is to long, you can write it like this:

```
    dictionary = change_dict_value(dictionary, specify_question,
                                   change_item)
```

Comments should have space after `#`, so:

```
# String variables
```

rather than:

```
#string variables
```

I'm finding writing docstrings for each and single function I write a very good practice. You can read more about docstrings formating in [PEP257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

It is also common to write:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

rather than

```
main()
```

It helps to reuse once written code by creating new modules and packages, while keeping ability to run script directly. For the reference about packages and modules read [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) about them.